# [8.0]How to set all fields in form view to read-only after setting state to confirmed

Tags: odoo, workflow, state, readonly

I need to know what command to add to the transition of DRAFT > CONFIRMED state of a document in ODOO-8 to make all fields READ ONLY.
I've attached an image below to see the fields that can be edited even though the state is confirmed.

I'm new to STACKOVERFLOW, thanks alot and i await replies

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `attrs` attribute to each field in the view definition like this:

```xml
<field name="field_name" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', '=', 'confirmed')]}"/>
```

Or, as @CZoellner said, you can do that in the .py:

```py
field_x = fields.Char(string="X", states={'confirmed': [('readonly', True)]})
```

Comment: Could you add the second possibility to your answer? You can do that on field definition, too, with code like `field_x = fields.Char(string="X", states={'confirmed': [('readonly', True)]})`

Comment: Yes, added that to the original answer

Comment: Thanks alot both @dccdany

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple states???
Like: states={'confirmed', draft': [('readonly', True)]})